# Which is the manufacturer and/or reference of those injectors?

Tags: toyota, yaris

I changed my engine and but as I took my own replacement engine not from France the repair shop can’t handle previous parts (mainly the broken engine).

The problem is how car scrapers works in France : I called many ones and they are refusing to take/buy parts without the whole car despite I have full proof of ownership over the item (maybe there is a French scrap yard this kind of thing but I didn’t found it). So I need to find an alternative way to get rid of them : my plan is just to sell them online but I need the reference.

As my car runs on ʟᴘɢ, the old injectors were reused in the replacement engine so the fuel rail below come from the new engine which has less than 13000Km :[image][image]
[image: brand]

The engine is 190000J060 compatible and it’s VIN code is VNKKL96380A230263 (manufactured in 2007). But as it’s a used engine I’m unsure if it’s still the OEM parts and there’s a name on those injector I can’t read but it’s not Toyota. I can also read `23250‒23020`.

Comment: Are you seriously expecting us to be able to give you a reference number just from a picture? How about the make, model, year and engine size? which if you have that info you should then be able to get the numbers yourself.

Comment: @SolarMike I updated the question with additional references (I can add additionnal pictures). But if they were changed I have no way to know the reference from engine history as the car scrapper destroyed the documents.

Comment: If you replaced your original engine with an "identical" one then you know what type, series & size it is.... Unless you were replacing a smaller engine with a larger one - but that is not so common now due to the stricter emission regulations...

Comment: @SolarMike both engines were originally running on E10 but the old one was converted to ʟᴘɢ/E85 use. So as I explained in the question, I used the old *(E85 compatible)* injectors instead of the gasoline injectors of the replacement engine (and this is those ones I’m intending to sell). Please edit my question if this is not enough clear.

Comment: @SolarMike I added the picture with what looks like to be the brand but I failed to find anything about that logo.

Comment: Any manufacturer stamped on the rest of the fuel system components? Bosch, Delphi etc that may be a start...

Comment: @SolarMike nothing. Maybe this is manufacturer’s logo, but I didn’t found anything with this.